# How to convert XML format to JSON format

Tags: json, angular, xml, typescript, angular7

I am getting an API response in XML format. How Can I convert XML to object? I getting API response below format. The Element col is not limited. It may be 5 to 10.

```
<xmlformat>
    <label1>data1</label1>
    <label2>data2</label2>
    <label3>data3</label3>
    <list>
        <col name="col">
            <datalist>
                <selectedlist>
                    <value>foo</value>
                </selectedlist>
                <optionList>
                <option label="foo" value="foo"></option>
                <optionList>
            </datalist>
            <datalist>
                <selectedlist>
                    <value>foo</value>
                </selectedlist>
                <optionList>
                <option label="foo" value="foo"></option>
                <option label="bar" value="bar"></option>
                <option label="baz" value="baz"></option>
                <optionList>
            </datalist>
        </col>
    </list>
```

Comment: please show us what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you use are using angular-cli to bootstrap into your application - it comes already with node module to convert xml.

https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js

You can try below function to convert xml to json

```
function convertXMLToJson(xmlContent) {
var result;
var parser = require('xml2js');
parser.Parser().parseString(xmlStr, (e, r) => {result = r});
return result; }
```

Comment: I am using DOMparser(). I am not interested in package